# Laravel Asset Manager and serving CSS/JS as modules

Tags: javascript, php, css, laravel, assets

I'm searching for days now for a proper way to serve the static content for my Laravel 4 website in a most optimal speed performance way. What I tend to obtain is serving only the needed JS and CSS, already minified to each requested page.

Example:

```
page1.html
-> styles.css - for this page it includes bootstrap.css, jquery-ui, selectize.css, google-custom-maps.css
-> scripts.js - for this page it includes boostrap.js, jquery.js, selectize.ks, google-custom-maps.js

page2.html
    -> styles.css - for this page it includes only bootstrap.css
    -> scripts.js - for this page it includes boostrap.js
```

Currently I have all my plugins installed with bower and using gulp tasks I managed to minify all the less, css and js scripts at once, the only problem is I don't know If it is possible to serve only the needed files for a custom page.

In my opinion an optimal solution would be that in each view.blade.php file i provide all the needed assests using

```
{{ asset('front/css/bootstrap.css') }}
{{ asset('front/css/jquery.css') }}
{{ asset('front/css/selectize.css') }}
```

And at first run this is compiled and cached. Is there any package that can do that?

Comment: Not a solution to your specific question, but is the total size of all minified resources that large? Because if it has a resonable size, you could merge all of them regardless of page requirements, to have a master `scripts.js` and `styles.css`. After the first request they'd be cached by the browser so you wouldn't need to worry about additional requests. This is of course reasonable if you can affort to set long expiration dates for the resources. You can use this [calculator](http://bit.ly/1Ak6GZT) to try to get a sense of how taking this approach would impact the resource download time.

Answer (score 0):

I have been always using template system where I include all the needed files in one place and other blade.php files extend this template.

Comment: ok, but this isn't a solution. I am too using the template system and including all scripts and css files there, but when viewing source I have multiple <script></script> tags and <link> tags, so there are multiple requests made for getting script and stylesheets

Comment: If your server is dying because of downloading static resources then I recommend to explore CDN solutions where these files are loaded from different server so your server will stay alive.